# Upstart init task

Tags: ubuntu, centos, upstart

Here is my use-case. I have a long running server that is started by upstart. This server needs to be initialized first (populate tables in a db). This should only happen once in the life of the service (and again on migration), so can't be tied to a start/stop action.

How can I set this up in upstart? Can I set this up without having "start myservice-init; start myservice" ?

Reposted from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24442123/upstart-init-task?noredirect=1#comment37820533_24442123 since it was put on hold there.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a way to check from sh whether the db population is needed? If so you can have it

```
start on starting myservice
task
pre-start script
    dbinitneeded || { stop; exit 0; }
end script
# init the db here with a script or exec
```

Comment: We want the setup to be explicit, so trying to figure out if a migration is needed is not something we can do.

Comment: Then just skip upstart entirely. Make it a little helper script, and exec it when needed.